# Image Hide-and-Seek

Tags: image-processing, fewest-operations

In this challenge, you need to find a specific pixel within an photograph (taken with a real camera).

You are passed an (R, G, B) tuple and an image, and **you need to return a point (x,y) within the image that matches the RGB color given**.  The image may have multiple points that match the color; you only need to find 1.

The *challenge* is that you need to do it **while reading as few pixels as possible**.  Your score will be total number of pixels read across all test cases.

If you wish, you can read the entire image into an array of RGB values, as long as you don't do any processing on the pixels.  I allow this purely for efficiency purposes.  For example, in Python, `list(Image.open("image_name+".jpg").convert("RGB").getdata())` is ok.

Hardcoding locations is not allowed.  Your algorithm should work well for more than just the test cases listed below.  You are not allowed to save data between test cases.  I've chosen RGB values that appear infrequently (`<10`) in the image (in case that makes a difference for your algorithm).  If you are using randomness in your algorithm, please set a seed, so that your score is constant.

Images can be found on [Github](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/images)

**Test cases:**

```
image_name: 
(r, g, b) [all possible answers]

barn:
(143,91,33) [(887,1096),(2226,1397),(2007,1402),(2161,1508),(1187,1702)]
(53,35,59) [(1999,1260)]
(20,24,27) [(1328,1087),(154,1271)]
(167,148,176) [(1748,1204)]
(137,50,7) [(596,1498)]
(116,95,94) [(1340,1123)]
(72,49,59) [(1344,857),(1345,858),(1380,926),(1405,974),(1480,1117)]
(211,163,175) [(1963,745)]
(30,20,0) [(1609,1462),(1133,1477),(1908,1632)]
(88,36,23) [(543,1494),(431,1575)]
daisy:
(21,57,91) [(1440,1935),(2832,2090),(2232,2130),(1877,2131),(1890,2132)]
(201,175,140) [(1537,1749),(2319,1757)]
(169,160,0) [(2124,759)]
(113,123,114) [(1012,994),(2134,1060),(1803,1183),(1119,1335)]
(225,226,231) [(3207,829),(3256,889),(3257,889),(1434,981),(2599,1118),(2656,1348),(2656,1351)]
(17,62,117) [(2514,3874),(2336,3885)]
(226,225,204) [(3209,812)]
(119,124,146) [(2151,974),(2194,1021),(2194,1022),(2202,1034),(2812,1500)]
(2,63,120) [(2165,3881),(2326,3882),(2330,3882),(2228,3887)]
(200,167,113) [(1453,1759)]
dandelion:
(55,2,46) [(667,825),(668,825)]
(95,37,33) [(1637,1721),(1625,1724),(1405,1753),(2026,2276),(2016,2298)]
(27,41,50) [(1267,126),(424,519),(2703,1323),(1804,3466)]
(58,92,129) [(2213,3274)]
(136,159,105) [(1300,2363),(2123,2645),(1429,3428),(1430,3432),(1417,3467),(1393,3490),(1958,3493)]
(152,174,63) [(2256,2556)]
(78,49,19) [(2128,2836)]
(217,178,205) [(2736,3531)]
(69,95,130) [(870,305),(493,460),(2777,1085),(2791,1292),(2634,3100)]
(150,171,174) [(2816,1201),(2724,2669),(1180,2706),(1470,3215),(1471,3215)]
gerbera:
(218,186,171) [(4282,1342)]
(180,153,40) [(4596,1634),(4369,1682),(4390,1708),(4367,1750)]
(201,179,119) [(4282,1876),(4479,1928)]
(116,112,149) [(5884,252),(4168,371),(4169,372),(4164,384),(5742,576)]
(222,176,65) [(4232,1548)]
(108,129,156) [(5341,3574),(5339,3595),(5302,3734)]
(125,99,48) [(4548,1825),(4136,1932),(5054,2013),(5058,2023),(5058,2035),(5055,2050),(5031,2073)]
(170,149,32) [(4461,1630),(4520,1640)]
(156,185,203) [(3809,108)]
(103,67,17) [(4844,1790)]
hot-air:
(48,21,36) [(1992,1029),(2005,1030),(2015,1034),(2018,1036)]
(104,65,36) [(3173,1890),(3163,1893)]
(169,89,62) [(4181,931),(4210,938),(4330,1046),(4171,1056),(3117,1814)]
(68,59,60) [(1872,220),(1874,220),(1878,220),(1696,225),(3785,429)]
(198,96,74) [(4352,1057)]
(136,43,53) [(1700,931)]
(82,42,32) [(4556,961),(4559,973),(4563,989),(4563,990),(4441,1004),(4387,1126),(4378,1128)]
(192,132,72) [(1399,900),(3105,1822),(3104,1824),(3105,1824),(3107,1826),(3107,1827),(3104,1839),(3119,1852)]
(146,21,63) [(1716,993)]
(125,64,36) [(4332,937)]
in-input:
(204,90,1) [(1526,1997),(1385,2145),(4780,2807),(4788,3414)]
(227,163,53) [(1467,1739),(2414,1925),(2441,2198),(134,2446)]
(196,179,135) [(3770,2740),(1110,3012),(3909,3216),(1409,3263),(571,3405)]
(208,59,27) [(1134,1980),(4518,2108),(4515,2142)]
(149,70,1) [(4499,1790),(2416,2042),(1338,2150),(3731,2408),(3722,2409),(4400,3618)]
(168,3,7) [(987,402),(951,432),(1790,1213),(1790,1214),(1848,1217),(4218,1840),(4344,1870),(1511,1898)]
(218,118,4) [(3857,1701),(1442,1980),(1411,2156),(25,2606)]
(127,153,4) [(3710,2813)]
(224,230,246) [(2086,160),(2761,222),(4482,1442)]
(213,127,66) [(4601,1860),(4515,2527),(4757,2863)]
klatschmohn:
(170,133,19) [(1202,2274),(1202,2275),(957,2493),(1034,2633),(3740,3389),(3740,3391),(3683,3439)]
(162,92,4) [(489,2854)]
(159,175,104) [(3095,2475),(3098,2481)]
(199,139,43) [(1956,3055)]
(171,169,170) [(3669,1487),(3674,1490),(3701,1507)]
(184,115,58) [(1958,2404)]
(228,169,5) [(1316,2336),(1317,2336)]
(179,165,43) [(3879,2380),(1842,2497),(1842,2498)]
(67,21,6) [(1959,2197),(2157,2317),(2158,2317),(2158,2318),(2116,2373)]
(213,100,106) [(1303,1816)]
tajinaste-rojo:
(243,56,99) [(1811,2876),(1668,4141),(2089,4518),(1981,4732),(1659,4778),(2221,5373),(1779,5598),(2210,5673),(2373,5860)]
(147,157,210) [(1835,1028),(1431,3358)]
(114,37,19) [(1792,3572),(1818,3592)]
(108,117,116) [(2772,4722),(1269,5672),(2512,5811),(2509,5830),(2186,5842),(2186,5846),(2190,5851),(2211,5884)]
(214,197,93) [(1653,4386)]
(163,102,101) [(2226,2832),(2213,3683),(1894,4091),(1875,4117)]
(192,192,164) [(2175,2962),(2206,3667),(2315,3858),(1561,3977),(3039,5037),(3201,5641)]
(92,118,45) [(1881,1704),(1983,1877),(2254,2126),(3753,5862),(3766,5883)]
(145,180,173) [(1826,1585)]
(181,124,105) [(1969,3892)]
turret-arch:
(116,70,36) [(384,648),(516,669)]
(121,115,119) [(2419,958)]
(183,222,237) [(172,601),(183,601),(110,611),(111,617)]
(237,136,82) [(2020,282),(676,383),(748,406),(854,482),(638,497),(647,661),(1069,838),(1809,895),(1823,911)]
(193,199,215) [(1567,919),(1793,1047)]
(33,30,25) [(1307,861),(309,885),(1995,895),(504,1232),(2417,1494)]
(17,23,39) [(1745,1033),(788,1090),(967,1250)]
(192,139,95) [(1445,1337)]
(176,125,98) [(1197,1030)]
(178,83,0) [(2378,1136)]
water-lilies:
(86,140,80) [(2322,2855),(4542,3005),(4540,3006),(4577,3019)]
(218,124,174) [(1910,2457)]
(191,77,50) [(2076,1588)]
(197,211,186) [(4402,1894)]
(236,199,181) [(2154,1836)]
(253,242,162) [(1653,1430)]
(114,111,92) [(1936,2499)]
(111,93,27) [(2301,2423),(2127,2592),(2137,2717),(2147,2717)]
(139,92,102) [(1284,2243),(1297,2258)]
(199,157,117) [(3096,993)]
```

Comment: Is there any correlation in the images we will be tested on? (Can images be noise) If not, surely the only way will be randomly sampling until the correct pixel is chosen?

Comment: @muddyfish the images are taken with real cameras of real objects, so there *is* optimization to be found.  Your algorithm should definitely be targeting the images, just not the specific colors I give.

Comment: "while reading as few pixels as possible" how do you determine this?

Comment: Due to differences in libraries and languages, I can't define methods that are considered "accessing". What in particular are you thinking about?

Comment: Should a solution output the number of pixels it checked?

Comment: @trichoplax you can certainly output that, if it makes counting the number of pixels it tests easier.   For scoring, I'd like algorithms to be deterministic, yes.

Comment: The barn.jpg image is 2600x1733 pixels yet you provide an (x,y) list `[(1096,887),(1397,2226),(1402,2007),(1508,2161),(1702,1187)]` that includes y values larger than 1733. Am I misunderstanding these lists?

Comment: @CarpetPython err....maybe I made them (y,x)?  Let me check

Comment: For the `barn` image, I get a pixel list of `[(612, 1131), (690, 1155), (784, 1065), (888, 1106), (900, 1729), (903, 1099), (980, 1498), (1581, 1420), (1661, 1529), (1811, 1484), (2140, 1650)]` for the `(143, 91, 33)` colour value. At least one of our programs has an error.

Comment: @CarpetPython Mine definitely had an error.  I'm not getting that many, but I *am* printing out (y,x) values instead of (x,y).  I've also separately verified that `(887, 1096)` has the correct value of `(143, 91, 33)`

Comment: I am still having problem replicating your result. My code: `def findpixels(fname):
    im = Image.open(fname+'.jpg');
    px = im.load();
    print 'TEST', px[(887, 1096)]` using `barn` prints `(142, 91, 38)`. Could you specify the origin (top left?) you are using? Maybe using 1-based rather than 0-based indexing?

Comment: You need `im.convert('RGB')`

Comment: I added `im.convert('RGB')` with same result. Python 2.7.10, Ubuntu Linux 64 bit. Can you verify that my code above (with `convert`) returns the expected colour on your machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40305/discussion-between-nathan-merrill-and-carpetpython).

Answer (score 5):

### Python, score: 14,035,624

First thing's first, here's the code:

```python
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from PIL import Image
import random

random.seed(1)


def dist(x, y):
    return sum([(x[i] - y[i]) ** 2 for i in range(3)])


def gradient_descent(image_name, c):
    im = Image.open(image_name + '.jpg').convert('RGB')
    L = im.load()
    sx, sy = im.size
    heap = []
    visited = set()
    count = 0
    points = []
    for i in range(0, sx, sx / 98):
        for j in range(0, sy, sy / 98):
            points.append((i, j))
    for x in points:
        heappush(heap, [dist(c, L[x[0], x[1]]), [x[0], x[1]]])
        visited.add((x[0], x[1]))

    while heap:
        if count % 10 == 0:
            x = random.random()
            if x < 0.5:
                n = heap.pop(random.randint(10, 100))
            else:
                n = heappop(heap)
        else:
            n = heappop(heap)
        x, y = n[1]
        c_color = L[x, y]
        count += 1

        if c_color == c:
            p = float(len(visited)) / (sx * sy) * 100
            print('count: {}, percent: {}, position: {}'.format(len(visited), p, (x, y)))
            return len(visited)

        newpoints = []
        newpoints.append((x + 1, y))
        newpoints.append((x - 1, y))
        newpoints.append((x, y + 1))
        newpoints.append((x, y - 1))
        newpoints.append((x + 1, y + 1))
        newpoints.append((x + 1, y - 1))
        newpoints.append((x - 1, y + 1))
        newpoints.append((x - 1, y - 1))

        for p in newpoints:
            if p not in visited:
                try:
                    d = dist(c, L[p[0], p[1]])
                    heappush(heap, [d, [p[0], p[1]]])
                    visited.add(p)
                except IndexError:
                    pass
```

and here's a gif showing how the algorithm examines pixels:
[image]

So, here's what this code is doing: The variable `heap` is a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) of `(x, y)` coordinates in the image, sorted by the Euclidean distance of the color at that coordinate to the target color. It gets initialized with 10,200 points which are evenly distributed across the entire image.

With the heap initialized, we then pop off the point with the minimum distance to the target color. If the color at that point has a distance > 0, that is to say, if the color at that point is NOT the target color, we add the 8 surrounding points from it to `heap`. To ensure that a given point isn't considered more than once, we maintain the variable `visited`, which is a set of all the points that have been examined so far.

Occasionally, instead of directly taking the point with the minimum color distance, we'll randomly choose some other point from *near* the top of the queue. This isn't strictly necessary, but in my testing, it shaves off approximately 1,000,000 pixels from the total score. Once the target color is found, we simply return the length of the `visited` set.

Like @Karl Napf, I ignored the test cases where the specified color was not present in the image. You can find a driver program to run through all the test cases at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Eppie/image-hide-and-seek) I created for this answer.

Here are the results from each specific test case:

```
barn
color: (143, 91, 33), count: 20388 / 0.452483465755%, position: (612, 1131)
color: (53, 35, 59), count: 99606 / 2.21061742643%, position: (1999, 1260)
color: (72, 49, 59), count: 705215 / 15.6512716943%, position: (1405, 974)

daisy
color: (21, 57, 91), count: 37393 / 0.154770711039%, position: (1877, 2131)
color: (169, 160, 0), count: 10659 / 0.0441179100089%, position: (2124, 759)
color: (113, 123, 114), count: 674859 / 2.79326096545%, position: (1119, 1335)
color: (225, 226, 231), count: 15905 / 0.0658312560927%, position: (3256, 889)
color: (17, 62, 117), count: 15043 / 0.0622634131029%, position: (2514, 3874)
color: (226, 225, 204), count: 138610 / 0.573710808362%, position: (1978, 1179)
color: (119, 124, 146), count: 390486 / 1.61623287435%, position: (2357, 917)
color: (2, 63, 120), count: 10063 / 0.0416510487306%, position: (2324, 3882)
color: (200, 167, 113), count: 16393 / 0.06785110224%, position: (1453, 1759)

dandelion
color: (95, 37, 33), count: 10081 / 0.0686342592593%, position: (1625, 1724)
color: (27, 41, 50), count: 2014910 / 13.7180691721%, position: (1267, 126)
color: (58, 92, 129), count: 48181 / 0.328029684096%, position: (1905, 756)
color: (136, 159, 105), count: 10521 / 0.0716299019608%, position: (1416, 3467)
color: (152, 174, 63), count: 10027 / 0.0682666122004%, position: (2256, 2558)
color: (69, 95, 130), count: 201919 / 1.37472086057%, position: (2708, 2943)
color: (150, 171, 174), count: 29714 / 0.202301198257%, position: (1180, 2706)

gerbera
color: (180, 153, 40), count: 21904 / 0.0906612910062%, position: (4459, 1644)
color: (116, 112, 149), count: 14896 / 0.0616549758413%, position: (5884, 252)
color: (222, 176, 65), count: 76205 / 0.315414704215%, position: (4313, 2097)
color: (108, 129, 156), count: 12273 / 0.0507983027994%, position: (5302, 3734)
color: (125, 99, 48), count: 26968 / 0.111621333814%, position: (5054, 2013)
color: (170, 149, 32), count: 89591 / 0.370819746281%, position: (4478, 1647)
color: (156, 185, 203), count: 177373 / 0.734151989118%, position: (4096, 368)
color: (103, 67, 17), count: 11035 / 0.0456741849093%, position: (4844, 1790)

hot-air
color: (48, 21, 36), count: 49711 / 0.24902994992%, position: (1990, 1095)
color: (104, 65, 36), count: 9927 / 0.0497298447599%, position: (3191, 1846)
color: (68, 59, 60), count: 195418 / 0.978957066918%, position: (3948, 470)
color: (82, 42, 32), count: 12216 / 0.0611967143737%, position: (4559, 984)
color: (192, 132, 72), count: 116511 / 0.583668171938%, position: (3103, 1844)

in-input
color: (204, 90, 1), count: 44058 / 0.248299807393%, position: (4695, 2559)
color: (227, 163, 53), count: 12654 / 0.0713147615132%, position: (221, 2384)
color: (196, 179, 135), count: 181534 / 1.02307996812%, position: (1030, 3486)
color: (208, 59, 27), count: 9956 / 0.0561095120614%, position: (4518, 2108)
color: (149, 70, 1), count: 13698 / 0.0771984829467%, position: (3731, 2408)
color: (168, 3, 7), count: 19381 / 0.10922644167%, position: (942, 398)
color: (218, 118, 4), count: 36648 / 0.206538911011%, position: (25, 2606)
color: (224, 230, 246), count: 1076427 / 6.06647185011%, position: (4482, 1442)
color: (213, 127, 66), count: 62673 / 0.353209265712%, position: (4701, 2579)

klatschmohn
color: (170, 133, 19), count: 11535 / 0.0724321530189%, position: (1034, 2633)
color: (162, 92, 4), count: 103795 / 0.651763790429%, position: (489, 2854)
color: (159, 175, 104), count: 10239 / 0.0642941321856%, position: (3098, 2481)
color: (171, 169, 170), count: 10119 / 0.063540611738%, position: (3674, 1490)
color: (184, 115, 58), count: 22425 / 0.140814133632%, position: (1958, 2404)
color: (228, 169, 5), count: 10449 / 0.0656127929688%, position: (1316, 2336)
color: (179, 165, 43), count: 10285 / 0.0645829816905%, position: (1842, 2498)
color: (67, 21, 6), count: 10206 / 0.0640869140625%, position: (2116, 2373)
color: (213, 100, 106), count: 11712 / 0.073543595679%, position: (1303, 1816)

tajinaste-rojo
color: (243, 56, 99), count: 126561 / 0.5273375%, position: (2241, 5424)
color: (114, 37, 19), count: 11285 / 0.0470208333333%, position: (1818, 3583)
color: (108, 117, 116), count: 33855 / 0.1410625%, position: (1269, 5672)
color: (163, 102, 101), count: 1058090 / 4.40870833333%, position: (1546, 4867)
color: (192, 192, 164), count: 10118 / 0.0421583333333%, position: (1919, 3171)
color: (92, 118, 45), count: 13431 / 0.0559625%, position: (3766, 5883)
color: (145, 180, 173), count: 1207713 / 5.0321375%, position: (1863, 955)

turret-arch
color: (116, 70, 36), count: 145610 / 3.23161258822%, position: (96, 671)
color: (183, 222, 237), count: 11704 / 0.259754094722%, position: (140, 604)
color: (237, 136, 82), count: 60477 / 1.34220338231%, position: (1063, 993)
color: (193, 199, 215), count: 359671 / 7.98240046163%, position: (2259, 953)
color: (33, 30, 25), count: 148195 / 3.28898308846%, position: (1307, 861)
color: (17, 23, 39), count: 10601 / 0.235274535044%, position: (2080, 1097)
color: (192, 139, 95), count: 219732 / 4.87664787607%, position: (1127, 970)
color: (176, 125, 98), count: 2471787 / 54.8578942696%, position: (147, 734)

water-lilies
color: (86, 140, 80), count: 10371 / 0.0717376936238%, position: (4542, 3005)
color: (218, 124, 174), count: 25655 / 0.177459312498%, position: (1910, 2457)
color: (197, 211, 186), count: 1144341 / 7.91557073177%, position: (4402, 1894)
color: (253, 242, 162), count: 14174 / 0.0980435897622%, position: (1672, 1379)
color: (111, 93, 27), count: 10405 / 0.0719728764975%, position: (2147, 2717)
color: (199, 157, 117), count: 10053 / 0.0695380420403%, position: (3096, 993)

Total: 14035624
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Nice algorithm too.

Comment: That nearest neighbour search with multiple seeds is great! I also considered using a BFS over a DFS with a heap just like you, but the quadsearch is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, score: 396,250,646

- While there are no PNGs to parse and there are still problems with the testcases, I decided to program anyway.
- Those testcases where the value is not present in the image were ignored (checked against a traditional linear search, which had a score of **544,017,431**)

```
from PIL import Image

def dist(x,y):
 d = 0
 for i in range(3):
  d += (x[i]-y[i])**2
 return d

def mid(x,y):
 return (x+y)/2

class Finder:
 def __init__(self, image_name, c):
  self.image_name = image_name,
  self.c = c
  self.found = False
  self.position = None
  self.im = Image.open(image_name+".jpg").convert("RGB")
  self.L = self.im.load()
  self.visited = set()

 def quadsearch(self,x0,x1,y0,y1):
  if x0==x1 and y0==y1: return
  xm=mid(x0,x1)
  ym=mid(y0,y1)
  R = [
   (x0,xm,y0,ym),
   (xm,x1,y0,ym),
   (x0,xm,ym,y1),
   (xm,x1,ym,y1),
   ]
  P = [(mid(t[0],t[1]), mid(t[2],t[3])) for t in R]
  DR = []
  for i in range(len(P)):
   p = P[i]
   if p in self.visited: continue
   self.visited.add(p)
   u = self.L[p[0], p[1]]
   d = dist(u, self.c)
   if d == 0:
    self.found = True
    self.position = (p[0], p[1])
    return
   DR.append((d,R[i]))
  S = sorted(range(len(DR)), key=lambda k: DR[k][0])
  for i in S:
   if self.found == True: return
   r = DR[i][1]
   self.quadsearch(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3])

 def start(self):
  sx,sy = self.im.size
  self.quadsearch(0,sx,0,sy)

 def result(self):
  if self.found:
   count = len(self.visited)
   sx,sy = self.im.size
   ratio = float(count)/(sx*sy)
   print len(self.visited), ratio, self.position, self.L[self.position[0], self.position[1]], "=", self.c
  else:
   print self.c, "not found"

if __name__ == "__main__":
 image_name="turret-arch"
 c=(116,70,36)
 F = Finder(image_name, c)
 F.start()
 F.result()
```

It is a recursive quad-section search. Sometimes it finds the correct value in a few percent, sometimes over 75%. Here are the results for all testcases:

`pixels_visited, percentage, (position) (RGB at position) = (RGB searched)`

```
tajinaste-rojo
1500765 0.062531875 (2329, 5146) (243, 56, 99) = (243, 56, 99)
(147, 157, 210) not found
335106 0.01396275 (2116, 5791) (114, 37, 19) = (114, 37, 19)
1770396 0.0737665 (1269, 5672) (108, 117, 116) = (108, 117, 116)
(214, 197, 93) not found
8086276 0.336928166667 (1546, 4867) (163, 102, 101) = (163, 102, 101)
12859 0.000535791666667 (1476, 4803) (192, 192, 164) = (192, 192, 164)
7505961 0.312748375 (3766, 5883) (92, 118, 45) = (92, 118, 45)
15057489 0.627395375 (1871, 1139) (145, 180, 173) = (145, 180, 173)
(181, 124, 105) not found
in-input
35754 0.00201500551852 (4695, 2559) (204, 90, 1) = (204, 90, 1)
5029615 0.283456451895 (10, 2680) (227, 163, 53) = (227, 163, 53)
6986547 0.393744217722 (1383, 3446) (196, 179, 135) = (196, 179, 135)
1608341 0.090642053775 (4518, 2108) (208, 59, 27) = (208, 59, 27)
581774 0.0327873194757 (3750, 2798) (149, 70, 1) = (149, 70, 1)
1302581 0.0734101891628 (4374, 1941) (168, 3, 7) = (168, 3, 7)
6134761 0.345739701008 (25, 2606) (218, 118, 4) = (218, 118, 4)
(127, 153, 4) not found
9760033 0.550050913352 (4482, 1442) (224, 230, 246) = (224, 230, 246)
212816 0.0119937745268 (4701, 2579) (213, 127, 66) = (213, 127, 66)
water-lilies
5649260 0.390767412093 (4577, 3019) (86, 140, 80) = (86, 140, 80)
12600699 0.871608412215 (1910, 2457) (218, 124, 174) = (218, 124, 174)
(191, 77, 50) not found
3390653 0.234536328318 (4402, 1894) (197, 211, 186) = (197, 211, 186)
(236, 199, 181) not found
7060220 0.488365537823 (1672, 1379) (253, 242, 162) = (253, 242, 162)
(114, 111, 92) not found
6852380 0.473988947097 (2147, 2717) (111, 93, 27) = (111, 93, 27)
(139, 92, 102) not found
14105709 0.975712111261 (3096, 993) (199, 157, 117) = (199, 157, 117)
dandelion
(55, 2, 46) not found
9094264 0.619162854031 (1637, 1721) (95, 37, 33) = (95, 37, 33)
2358912 0.16060130719 (1526, 3129) (27, 41, 50) = (27, 41, 50)
11729837 0.798600013617 (1905, 756) (58, 92, 129) = (58, 92, 129)
6697060 0.455954520697 (2246, 2685) (136, 159, 105) = (136, 159, 105)
6429635 0.437747480937 (2148, 2722) (152, 174, 63) = (152, 174, 63)
(78, 49, 19) not found
(217, 178, 205) not found
80727 0.00549611928105 (2481, 3133) (69, 95, 130) = (69, 95, 130)
239962 0.0163372821351 (2660, 917) (150, 171, 174) = (150, 171, 174)
turret-arch
210562 0.0467313240712 (725, 655) (116, 70, 36) = (116, 70, 36)
(121, 115, 119) not found
2548703 0.565649385237 (140, 604) (183, 222, 237) = (183, 222, 237)
150733 0.033453104887 (2165, 601) (237, 136, 82) = (237, 136, 82)
3458188 0.767497003862 (2259, 953) (193, 199, 215) = (193, 199, 215)
2430256 0.539361711572 (265, 1222) (33, 30, 25) = (33, 30, 25)
638995 0.141816103689 (1778, 1062) (17, 23, 39) = (17, 23, 39)
2506522 0.556287895601 (1127, 970) (192, 139, 95) = (192, 139, 95)
1344400 0.298370988504 (147, 734) (176, 125, 98) = (176, 125, 98)
(178, 83, 0) not found
hot-air
17474837 0.875411434688 (1992, 1029) (48, 21, 36) = (48, 21, 36)
1170064 0.0586149905099 (3191, 1846) (104, 65, 36) = (104, 65, 36)
(169, 89, 62) not found
11891624 0.595717352134 (3948, 470) (68, 59, 60) = (68, 59, 60)
(198, 96, 74) not found
(136, 43, 53) not found
12476811 0.625032612198 (4387, 1126) (82, 42, 32) = (82, 42, 32)
4757856 0.238347376116 (3105, 1822) (192, 132, 72) = (192, 132, 72)
(146, 21, 63) not found
(125, 64, 36) not found
daisy
5322196 0.220287235367 (2171, 2128) (21, 57, 91) = (21, 57, 91)
(201, 175, 140) not found
22414990 0.9277629343 (2124, 759) (169, 160, 0) = (169, 160, 0)
20887184 0.864526601043 (1119, 1335) (113, 123, 114) = (113, 123, 114)
595712 0.0246566923794 (2656, 1349) (225, 226, 231) = (225, 226, 231)
3397561 0.140626034757 (2514, 3874) (17, 62, 117) = (17, 62, 117)
201068 0.00832226281046 (1978, 1179) (226, 225, 204) = (226, 225, 204)
18693250 0.773719036752 (2357, 917) (119, 124, 146) = (119, 124, 146)
3091040 0.127939041706 (2165, 3881) (2, 63, 120) = (2, 63, 120)
3567932 0.147677739839 (1453, 1759) (200, 167, 113) = (200, 167, 113)
barn
314215 0.0697356740202 (784, 1065) (143, 91, 33) = (143, 91, 33)
2448863 0.543491277908 (1999, 1260) (53, 35, 59) = (53, 35, 59)
(20, 24, 27) not found
(167, 148, 176) not found
(137, 50, 7) not found
(116, 95, 94) not found
2042891 0.453391406631 (1345, 858) (72, 49, 59) = (72, 49, 59)
(211, 163, 175) not found
(30, 20, 0) not found
(88, 36, 23) not found
klatschmohn
3048249 0.191409829222 (3683, 3439) (170, 133, 19) = (170, 133, 19)
1057649 0.0664133456509 (489, 2854) (162, 92, 4) = (162, 92, 4)
2058022 0.129230138206 (3095, 2475) (159, 175, 104) = (159, 175, 104)
(199, 139, 43) not found
2060805 0.129404892156 (3674, 1490) (171, 169, 170) = (171, 169, 170)
7725501 0.485110247577 (1958, 2404) (184, 115, 58) = (184, 115, 58)
2986734 0.187547095028 (1316, 2336) (228, 169, 5) = (228, 169, 5)
497709 0.0312528257017 (3879, 2379) (179, 165, 43) = (179, 165, 43)
3996978 0.250983720944 (2157, 2318) (67, 21, 6) = (67, 21, 6)
3332106 0.209234167028 (1303, 1816) (213, 100, 106) = (213, 100, 106)
gerbera
(218, 186, 171) not found
9445576 0.390955128952 (4377, 1750) (180, 153, 40) = (180, 153, 40)
(201, 179, 119) not found
6140398 0.254152853347 (5742, 576) (116, 112, 149) = (116, 112, 149)
6500717 0.269066561215 (4233, 1541) (222, 176, 65) = (222, 176, 65)
13307056 0.550782905612 (5302, 3734) (108, 129, 156) = (108, 129, 156)
13808847 0.571552180573 (5058, 2023) (125, 99, 48) = (125, 99, 48)
9454870 0.391339810307 (4478, 1647) (170, 149, 32) = (170, 149, 32)
2733978 0.113160142012 (4096, 368) (156, 185, 203) = (156, 185, 203)
11848606 0.490417237301 (4844, 1790) (103, 67, 17) = (103, 67, 17)
```